# Flutter: Changing color by comparing final object and edited object

Tags: flutter, dart

Using `setState` changes the `widget.object` value when editing

Example: Trying to change color when editing a name by comparing `widget.person` and `_person`

```
class EditPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Person person;

  EditPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.person,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditPageState createState() => _EditPageState();
}

class _EditPageState extends State<EditPage> {
  final Person _person;

  @override
  void initState() {
  _person = widget.person;

  }

  
  bool _hasChanges(Person person){
    bool _result = false;

    if(person.name != widget.person.name {
      _result = true
      }
  
    return _result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        ...
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.check,
              color: _hasChanges(_person)
                  ? Colors.yellow
                  : Colors.white,
            ),
            ...
          ),
        ],
        ...
      ),
      body: TextFormField(
                onChanged: (value){
                  _person.name = value;
                },
                onFieldSubmitted: (value){
                  setState(() {});
                },
                
              ),
    ...
   );
  }
}
```

This code does not change the icon color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, all your tries will going to be fail.

You need to know that `_person = widget.person` is a refrence not a clone, so when you change the name of `_person` you also change the name of `widget.person` too.

So I suggest two ways:

First one, to make a method in class person to be cloned with all its properties.

Second one, to save only the name in String variable and you can progress with same code you have.

```
String _personName;

_personName = widget.person.name;
```

Comment: Would `ValueListenableBuilder` and `ValueNotifier` make things easier to check if something in the `Object` was changed ?

Comment: They will help you in state management of course, but the same problem will be there, you should save old value of name in variable without being a refrence to person from parent widget.